# Executable Packer (decompression/decryption stub)

Tags: c, inline-assembly, packing, portable-executable

I am working on an executable Packer & I have done compression & Encryption part so far. Now I have to store decompression/decryption stub/routine in the compressed file. My question is that will this stub be written in HEX code or I can place the assembly instruction directly ? If later is possible, then how ?

Comment: look at the structure of some executable packed by UPX. this may help you.

Comment: Thanks @V-X I have analyzed UPX source but clearly I couldn't understand what is the format of stub(i.e hex/assembly) and how do they place it. An help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a working packed binary requires:

1. modify the PE geometry
2. insert your code

Depending on your code size, you might want to use section padding, or to add your own section.

Then, to insert your code - as you seem to prefer direct ASM insertion - my suggestion would be to make the decryption code EIP-independent, then assemble it with something like YASM as pure code (`-o`), and include the code as assembled binary directly.

I wrote several [mini-packers](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/corkami/mini_packers.zip) that might help as a starting reference, as they also 'insert' assembled code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ange,that suggestion was helpful. Yes, I have modified PE geometry. I'm also adding a new section for that stub part. But now the problem is that I compress & Encrypt the file. Create a new section where I will be placing my stub portion, I create a new PE file using header info of input file, apply modifications to newly created file. Everything seems fine i.e headers etc.But when I run the file I see error message "not a valid Win32 application".I am using Visual Studio 2010 & no-incremental-linking.I can't figure out what the problem is? Maybe you can suggest a better solution?

Comment: this could have *many* reasons (forgot to increase SizeOfImage, ... ?), so you should try and open your new PE with [pefile](https://code.google.com/p/pefile/) and see what the warnings tell you.

Comment: I have increased the SizeOfImage.Can you tell me if I am doing this the right way i.e SizeOfImage=stubSection->VirtualAddress+stubSection->Misc.VirtualSize where stubSection is last section. If this way of computation is wrong what is right method of increasing SizeOfImage? I'm also opening my PE with LordPE & PEiD but they don't tell any warnings. What possibly could be other reasons, MajorLinkerVersion, OSversion etc ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have section with characteristic as "readable" & "writable" & "contains code" & "Is executable"

```
  Address of Entry Point:        0x00019860

  Section Header #1
    Name:                             UPX0
    Virtual Size:                     0x00010000 (65536)
    Virtual Address:                  0x00001000
    Size of Raw Data:                 0x00000000 (0)
    File Pointer to Raw Data:         0x00000400
    File Pointer to Relocation Table: 0x00000000
    File Pointer to Line Numbers:     0x00000000
    Number of Relocations:            0
    Number of Line Numbers:           0
    Characteristics:                  0xE0000080
      Section contains uninitialized data.
      Section is executable.
      Section is readable.
      Section is writeable.

  Section Header #2
    Name:                             UPX1
    Virtual Size:                     0x00009000 (36864)
    Virtual Address:                  0x00011000
    Size of Raw Data:                 0x00008A00 (35328)
    File Pointer to Raw Data:         0x00000400
    File Pointer to Relocation Table: 0x00000000
    File Pointer to Line Numbers:     0x00000000
    Number of Relocations:            0
    Number of Line Numbers:           0
    Characteristics:                  0xE0000040
      Section contains initialized data.
      Section is executable.
      Section is readable.
      Section is writeable.

  Section Header #3
    Name:                             .rsrc
    Virtual Size:                     0x00001000 (4096)
    Virtual Address:                  0x0001A000
    Size of Raw Data:                 0x00000800 (2048)
    File Pointer to Raw Data:         0x00008E00
    File Pointer to Relocation Table: 0x00000000
    File Pointer to Line Numbers:     0x00000000
    Number of Relocations:            0
    Number of Line Numbers:           0
    Characteristics:                  0xC0000040
      Section contains initialized data.
      Section is readable.
      Section is writeable.
```

Just in short, UPX generates one section which contains compressed code and decompressor routine and second section which is uninitialized but is allowed to have writable and executable characteristic. The decompressor routine decompresses the code to the uninitialized section and continues with execution of the original entrypoint...

Comment: I have created a new section for placing stub that has the RWE characteristics. But the problem isn't with the sections. It's what should be the format of decompression/decryption stub i.e it should be in assembly or HEX (like shellcode) ?

Comment: I still don't see the difference between writing assembly as binary or writing that as assembly instructions, which are later compiled into binary...

Comment: Ok, suppose I have chosen the second option .i.e writing as assembly instructions. Now how do I place these instructions into my stub section ? Because I need to have some kind of buffer that stores these instructions and write the buffer into file ?